# Calling Navigation.PushAsync() from a class file that is called by another ContentPage in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a .cs file in my project that is not related to any `Pages` and it is called by the `MainPage`.

Calling `await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage());` has as a result the following error:
`Error CS0103 The name 'Navigation' does not exist in the current context`.

Changing the `Class` definition from `class MyClass` to `class MyClass : MainPage` the error changes to: `Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'NavigableElement.Navigation'`

Which is the correct way to call `Navigation.PushAsync()` without errors?

Comment: You can reference the active page via App.Current.MainPage and use its Navigation property

Comment: Indeed, it works. Post it as an answer if you wish and I'll accept it. Thanks, by the way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `App.Current.MainPage` to get a reference to the active page (you may need to cast it) and then use it's `Navigation` property